# Specific errors messages for each input if not found in the database

Tags: function, exception, plsql, error-handling

I have developed the following function. I have been instructed that the function should return null if no teacher is found in the database. If the function returns null then it should output “no teacher found.” The code below accomplishes this. However, I would like to output specific responses if errors are made when keying in any of the 4 inputs. For instance, in addition to receiving the response “no teacher found” it would also say “subject not found” or “school not found.” Basically, if any of the 4 inputs was keyed in incorrectly, it would be clear as to the reason the function returned null. That way, if the a school name was misspelled by a single letter, the problem would be clear and evident instead of thinking that no teacher taught that particular class. How can I accomplish this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_classroom_teacher(
    subject_in      IN      subjects.subject%TYPE,
    school_name_in  IN      schools.school_name%TYPE,
    year_in         IN      classrooms.year%TYPE,
    semester_in     IN      classrooms.semester%TYPE)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    l_teacher_name VARCHAR2(50);
    
BEGIN    
 
    SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_name
    INTO l_teacher_name
    FROM people
    WHERE school_id IN (
        SELECT school_id
        FROM schools
        WHERE school_name = school_name_in)
    AND
    person_id IN (
        SELECT person_id
        FROM teachers
        WHERE subject_id IN (
            SELECT subject_id
            FROM subjects
            WHERE subject = subject_in)
        AND subject_id IN (
            SELECT subject_id
            FROM classrooms
            WHERE semester = semester_in
            AND year = year_in));
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_teacher_name);
   RETURN l_teacher_name;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
         RETURN NULL;
 
END get_classroom_teacher;
```

I call it like this:

```
DECLARE
    l_subject      subjects.subject%TYPE;
    l_school       schools.school_name%TYPE;
    l_year         classrooms.year%TYPE;
    l_semester     classrooms.semester%TYPE;
    l_teacher_name VARCHAR2(60);
BEGIN
    l_subject      := 'Science';
    l_school       := 'Fayetteville-Manlius School';
    l_year         := 2021;
    l_semester     := 'spring';
    l_teacher_name := get_classroom_teacher(l_subject, l_school, l_year, l_semester);
    IF l_teacher_name IS NULL THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No teacher found.');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The teacher is ' || l_teacher_name);
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'An error was encountered - ' ||
                                             SQLCODE ||
                                             ' -ERROR- ' ||
                                             SQLERRM);
END;
```

Comment: If either of the given answers resolved your issue then please accept it. If you found another solution then post that and accept it. Accepting an answer helps future questioners having the same basic question. If you still have issues then revise your question. Either way please do not just leave the question unresolved.

Comment: The answers didn't provide a solution so it is still unresolved.

Comment: Then you need tp provide [mcve]. This would include table definitions (DDL), specific input as formatted text - **no images**, and exact output from that input, code and current output.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you face is that any of inputs may be the cause of a "No Data Found" exception. Further there could actually be multiple invalid parameters, i.e school and subject misspelled. To determine the exact cause then you must select each parameter independently. This could be a performance killer. Since we assume the majority of requests will be successful you can delay those selections until after the full query fails, then on a no data found exception do the individual selects. Since each individual then must also trap NO_DATA_FOUND you can create helper functions for them.

```
create or replace 
function teacher_name(subject_in      IN      subjects.subject%TYPE 
                     ,school_name_in  IN      schools.school_name%TYPE
                     ,year_in         IN      classrooms.year%TYPE
                     ,semester_in     IN      classrooms.semester%TYPE
                     )
  return  varchar2 
is
    l_teacher   varchar2(50);
    l_school_id schools.school_id%TYPE;
    l_subject_id subjects.subject_id%TYPE;    
    l_year      classrooms.year%TYPE;
    l_classroom classrooms.semester%TYPE;
    
     procedure what_school() is 
     begin
        select school_id
         into l_school_id
         from schools
        where school_name = school_name_in)
    exception 
       when no_data_found then l_school_id = null;
       when too_many_rows then l_school_id = 0;
    end what_school; 
    
    procedure what_subject() is 
    begin
        select subject_id
         into l_subject_id
         from subjects
        where subject_name = subject_name_in)
    exception 
       when no_data_found then null; 
       when too_many_rows then subject_id = 0;
    end what_subject;  
    
    -- Functions for semester, year ...
    
begin 
    << Your query here >> 
    return the_teacher; 
exception 
    when no_data_found then 
        l_school_id  := when_school; 
        l_subject_id := what_subject; 
        l_year       := what_year; 
        l_semester   := what_semester;
        
        if  l_school_id is null then 
            dbms_output.put_line( ' No such school as: ' || school_name_in;
        if  l_subject_id is null then 
            dbms_output.put_line( ' No such subject as: ' || subject_in;
        if  l_year is null then 
            dbms_output.put_line( ' No such yeear as: ' || year_in;
        if  l_semester is null then 
            dbms_output.put_line( ' No such semester as: ' || semester_id;            
        if  l_school_id is not null 
        and l_subject_id is not null 
        and l_year is not null
        and l_semester is not null 
        then
            dbms_output.put_line( ' No Date Found') 
            return null;
        end if;
```

end teacher_name;

NOTE: No sample data nor table DDL; Not Tested.

Answer (score 0):

We can define bespoke exceptions and raise them in procedures. EXCEPTION is a PL/SQL data type, and we can associate an error number from the range set aside for user-defined exceptions (-20999 to -20000) using the `exception_init` pragma. So your function might look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_classroom_teacher(
    subject_in      IN      subjects.subject%TYPE,
    school_name_in  IN      schools.school_name%TYPE,
    year_in         IN      classrooms.year%TYPE,
    semester_in     IN      classrooms.semester%TYPE)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    l_teacher_name VARCHAR2(50);
    
    x_subject_null      exception;
    pragma exception_init (x_subject_null,     -20000);
    x_school_name_null  exception;
    pragma exception_init (x_school_name_null, -20001);
    x_semester_null     exception;
    pragma exception_init (x_semester_null,    -20002);
    x_year_null         exception;
    pragma exception_init (x_year_null,        -20003);
     
BEGIN
    if subject_in is null then
      raise x_subject_null; 
    elsif school_name_in is null then
      raise x_school_name_null; 
    elsif subject_in is null then
      raise x_semester_null; 
    elsif year_in is null then
      raise x_year_null; 
    end if;      
 
    SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_name
    INTO l_teacher_name
    FROM people
    WHERE school_id IN (
        SELECT school_id
        FROM schools
        WHERE school_name = school_name_in)
    AND
    person_id IN (
        SELECT person_id
        FROM teachers
        WHERE subject_id IN (
            SELECT subject_id
            FROM subjects
            WHERE subject = subject_in)
        AND subject_id IN (
            SELECT subject_id
            FROM classrooms
            WHERE semester = semester_in
            AND year = year_in));
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_teacher_name);
   RETURN l_teacher_name;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
         RETURN NULL;
END get_classroom_teacher;
```

The catch is those user-defined exceptions are only useful within the scope of the function. They are no different from any other variable defined in a standalone program unit. Consequently, your calling block cannot reference them, which means you cannot log a bespoke error message for each exception.

The solution is to define the exceptions in a package spec which can be referenced by both the function *and* the anonymous block.

```
create or replace package ude as

    x_subject_null      exception;
    pragma exception_init (x_subject_null,     -20000);
    x_school_name_null  exception;
    pragma exception_init (x_school_name_null, -20001);
    x_semester_null     exception;
    pragma exception_init (x_semester_null,    -20002);
    x_year_null         exception;
    pragma exception_init (x_year_null,        -20003); 
end;
/
```

Reference the package in your function ....

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_classroom_teacher(
    subject_in      IN      subjects.subject%TYPE,
    school_name_in  IN      schools.school_name%TYPE,
    year_in         IN      classrooms.year%TYPE,
    semester_in     IN      classrooms.semester%TYPE)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    l_teacher_name VARCHAR2(50);
     
BEGIN
    if subject_in is null then
      raise ude.x_subject_null; 
    elsif school_name_in is null then
      raise ude.x_school_name_null; 
    elsif subject_in is null then
      raise ude.x_semester_null; 
    elsif year_in is null then
      raise ude.x_year_null; 
    end if;      
 
    SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_name
    INTO l_teacher_name
    FROM people
    WHERE school_id IN (
        SELECT school_id
        FROM schools
        WHERE school_name = school_name_in)
    AND
    person_id IN (
        SELECT person_id
        FROM teachers
        WHERE subject_id IN (
            SELECT subject_id
            FROM subjects
            WHERE subject = subject_in)
        AND subject_id IN (
            SELECT subject_id
            FROM classrooms
            WHERE semester = semester_in
            AND year = year_in));
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_teacher_name);
   RETURN l_teacher_name;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
         RETURN NULL;
 
END get_classroom_teacher;
```

and in your calling block ....

```
DECLARE
    l_subject      subjects.subject%TYPE;
    l_school       schools.school_name%TYPE;
    l_year         classrooms.year%TYPE;
    l_semester     classrooms.semester%TYPE;
    l_teacher_name VARCHAR2(60);
BEGIN
    l_subject      := 'Science';
    l_school       := 'Fayetteville-Manlius School';
    l_year         := 2021;
    l_semester     := 'spring';
    l_teacher_name := get_classroom_teacher(l_subject, l_school, l_year, l_semester);
    IF l_teacher_name IS NULL THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No teacher found.');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The teacher is ' || l_teacher_name);
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    when  ude.x_subject_null then
        dbms_output.put_line ('Subject parameter was null'); 
        raise;
    when ude.x_school_name_null then
        dbms_output.put_line ('School name parameter was null');  
        raise
    when ude.x_semester_null then
        dbms_output.put_line ('Semester parameter was null'); 
        raise;
    when ude.x_year_null then
        dbms_output.put_line ('Year parameter was null'); 
        raise;

    WHEN OTHERS THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'An error was encountered - ' ||
                                             SQLCODE ||
                                             ' -ERROR- ' ||
                                             SQLERRM);
END;
```

You may choose not to re-raise those handled exceptions.

Generally speaking, a WHEN OTHERS branch like that is considered bad practice. You're suppressing some useful information without getting anything in return. WHEN OTHERS is useful when we want to take some action for all exceptions, such as writing a message to a log table. But just re-raising every error with a single ERRNO is pointless.